# Era-Interim - different value in output from R and ArcGIS

Tags: python, r, python-2.7

I’m new to R language and I need a help :)
So, I got temperature data from Era-Interim reanalysis (from surface and few model levels) and would like to open that file in R. I did by using such code:

```
library(chron)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(lattice)
library(ncdf4)
getwd()
workdir <- "C:\\Users\\Angelika\\Documents\\Reanalysis\\06\\03"
setwd(workdir)
# model levels
ncname <- "03"
ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
dname1 <- "t"
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "longitude")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "latitude")
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)
level <- ncvar_get(ncin, "level")
nlevel <- dim(level)
head(level)
t <- ncvar_get(ncin, "time")
tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin, "time", "units")
nt <- dim(t)
head(t)
print(c(nlon, nlat, nlevel, nt))
tmp.array1 <- ncvar_get(ncin, dname1)
dlname1 <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname1, "long_name")
dunits1 <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname1, "units")
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname1, "_FillValue")
dim(tmp.array1)
title <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "title")
institution <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "institution")
datasource <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "source")
references <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "references")
history <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "history")
conventions <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "Conventions")
tmp.vec.long1 <- as.vector(tmp.array1)
length(tmp.vec.long1)
tmp.mat1 <- matrix(tmp.vec.long1, nrow = nlon * nlat, ncol = nlevel)
dim(tmp.mat1)
head(na.omit(tmp.mat1)) 
tlonlat1 <- expand.grid(t,lon, lat)
tmp.df02t <- data.frame(cbind(tlonlat1, tmp.mat1))
names(tmp.df02t) <- c("t", "lon", "lat", "t39", "t40", "t41", "t42", "t43", "t44", "t45", "t46", "t47", "t48", "t49", "t50", "t51", "t52", "t53", "t54", "t55", "t56", "t57", "t58", "t59", "t60")
head(na.omit(tmp.df02t, 20))

# surface = t2m
ncname <- "03_surface"
ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
dname3 <- "t2m"
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "longitude")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "latitude")
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)
t <- ncvar_get(ncin, "time")
tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin, "time", "units")
nt <- dim(t)
head(t)
print(c(nlon, nlat, nt))
tmp.array3 <- ncvar_get(ncin, dname3)
dlname <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname3, "long_name")
dunits <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname3, "units")
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin, dname3, "_FillValue")
dim(tmp.array3)
title <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "title")
institution <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "institution")
datasource <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "source")
references <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "references")
history <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "history")
conventions <- ncatt_get(ncin, 0, "Conventions")
tmp.vec.long3 <- as.vector(tmp.array3)
length(tmp.vec.long3)
tmp.mat <- matrix(tmp.vec.long3, nrow = nlon * nlat *nt)
dim(tmp.mat)
head(na.omit(tmp.mat)) 
tlonlat <- expand.grid(t,lon, lat)
tmp.df02t2m <- data.frame(cbind(tlonlat, tmp.mat))
names(tmp.df02t2m) <- c("t", "lon", "lat", "t2m")
head(na.omit(tmp.df02t2m))
table<- merge(tmp.df02t2m , tmp.df02t, by=c("t","lon", "lat"))
csvfile <- "03_data.csv"
write.table(na.omit(table), csvfile, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Unfortunately, after interpolation I got some strange results. I checked it again by opening  NetCDF in ArcGIS 10.1 and Python and temperature value -  was sometimes completly different between, but only on selected grids and days (in ArcGIS everything was fine). What did I do wrong in R language? Why  do such differences occur?
Best regards ;)

Comment: Hi Did you managed to sort this, I am having similar issue in R . Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the use of na.omit() may be the reason for spurious averages. Most probably you lose part of the "non NA" data this way. In R, averages can be safely calculated from NA containing vectors or matrices.